# Propositional Logic model

Tags: logic

In propositional logic, "model" is defined as mathematical abstractions that fix the truth or falsehood of every relevant sentence? How is relevance defined in this case?

Comment: I was reading it for propositional logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mean by *"relevant sentences"* is vague. In propositional logic, models are **valuations**, that is, mappings $v: FORM \mapsto \{0,1\}$ from the set of well-formed formulae FORM to the Boolean set {0,1}. However, if what you mean in your question by *"models are defined as mathematical abstractions that fix the truth or falsehood of every relevant sentence"* is that interpretations are confined to the set of **well-formed formulae** only (the set of "grammatically correct" sentences of a language), you answer is: yes.

Comment: Okay. So as long as the sentence is syntactically correct, a model can be formed. right?

Comment: @user1989682 It depends on what do you mean by *"a model can be formed"*. Note that a formula $\phi$ can be well-formed, but *unsatisfiable*, which means that there is no model $M$ in which $\phi$ is true. In symbols: $\nvDash_M \phi$. In usual terminology, this kind of formulae are called **invalid**. In the particular case where the formula $\phi$ is propositional we call it a *contradiction*.